# Return value from a cmd function

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch function and I need to return a value from it. Following is the script:

```
@echo off
call :Mode mode1
echo mode is %mode1%

:Mode
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (map.txt) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set var[!count!]=%%x
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in ("%var[2]%") Do (
    set mode=OPEN
)
IF %mode%==OPEN (
    echo coming into open
    set %1=OPEN
    echo %mode1%
) ELSE (
    echo coming into shorted
    set %1=SHORTED
    echo %mode1%
) 
EXIT /B 0
```

`echo mode is %mode1%` doesn't print anything. Any help? I've hardcoded `set mode=OPEN` for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `exit`, `exit /b` or `goto :eof` implicitly does an `endlocal`, so you need a trick for your variable `%1` to survive an `endlocal`. `endlocal & set ... & goto :eof` does the trick because the whole line gets parsed in one go:

```
@echo off
call :Mode mode1
echo mode is %mode1%
goto :eof

:Mode
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "mode=OPEN"
IF "%mode%" == "OPEN" (
    echo coming into open
    endlocal&set "%1=OPEN"&goto :eof
) ELSE (
    echo coming into shorted
    endlocal&set "%1=SHORTED"&goto :eof
)
```

For the [same reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028), `echo %mode1%` in your subroutine does not print the variable.

Note: I changed `set` and `if` syntax to recommended quoted syntax.